# Why do properties show they are NOT public?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Label I am trying to bind to a property.  My `DataContext` is a `public Class` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

---

**My property is defined in my public class like this:**

```
    public string ProgressMessage
    {
        get { return _progressMessage; }
        set 
        {
            if (_progressMessage != value)
            {
                _progressMessage = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgressMessage");                
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**So why in the world does it show up in intellisense like this (NOT public):**

[image]

---

**Is this why does my label not update when I change the value of** `ProgressMessage`??

I have done the `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and every other combination I can think of, can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide small complete sample of what does not work. One label, one viewmodel with one property you bind to, etc. As is - not reproducible.

Comment: I get the same lock icon in VS 2015, however my label updates correctly when `ProgressMessage` changes. So your binding is not working for some other reason.

Comment: Is this the only property that does not work? Are there other properties in the same class that do work?

Comment: This is just a guess. Look like the problem is not at your property. It's at your class level. Seems like all of your properties are locked e.g. SelectedJob and OpenResourceCommand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the symbol you see that kind of looks like a lock is not actually a lock.  Instead it seems to be identifying properties on the data context that you can to bind to. I was able to recreate this issue and successfully binded to a property that had the symbol.

If you go ahead and type {Binding Path= You will see that it only shows you possible binding paths:
[image: Path example]

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right about that symbol, something else wrong with my binding